# Expiring a Cookie after 30 days

Tags: cookies

I'm just need to make sure I have this correct. I don't have 30days (or even a day) to test this.

```
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

I think all I have to do is add this line of code:

```
    var days = "30";
```

Is this correct? How can I test that this works after 1 minute while still using the days var? I'm not very good at math :x

Comment: date.setTime() uses milliseconds. 1000 millisecond=1 second, 60 second=1 minute, 60 minute=1 hour, 24 hours is one day. So 1day=24(hours)*60(minutes)*60(seconds)*1000(milliseconds). If you need to test a future minute forget the days variable and just use date.setTime(date.getTime()+(60*1000)).

Comment: Yeah I got you on that thanks. I was hoping to test that the variable days will work when the time comes. I guess I was wondering what is 1/1,440 of a day and would I be able to use that for the days variable.

Comment: Leaving the code as it is you can use 1/1440 for the days value to give you  almost (1/1440=6.94444444444...) a minute.

Answer (score 0):

I can rest easy knowing everything is working.
I am testing every half-minute with the code below.

```
var days = "0.00034722222";
```